# Fetching the value from mysql array and match from the field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got stuck in minor error on which I am trying to fetch the value from mysql.

Array and matching the value from field, but I am getting an error.

Can you please check my code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['newsletter'])){
$email=$_POST['email'];
$check=mysql_query("select email from newsletter");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  if($row['email'])==$email){
    echo "<script> alert('You are already Subscribed');</script>";
 } else {
 $sql_news=mysql_query("insert into newsletter(email) values('$email')");
  echo "<script> alert('You are successfully Subscribed');</script>"; 
 }}} ?>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What's that `)` doing there after `if($row['email'] ...`?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [**And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Use PDO instead.

Comment: I understand thats an error but still i am not getting an proper result

Comment: where is your 
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query)
$query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update this line cause you use $check value so in mysql fetch use this

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

to

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($check))
```

Comment: its ok, carry on